# Invisible attribute of super()'s returned class (Inheritance)

Tags: python, oop

Look at this simple code that uses inheritance:

```
class A:
    def f(self):
        pass
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
b = B()
print(dir(b))
```

As expected, this list includes the method `f` and the output is

> `['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'f']`

But now, look at this code instead:

```
class A:
    def f(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        global s
        s = super()
b = B()
print(dir(s))
print(s.f)
```

The output is

> `['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__self__', '__self_class__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__thisclass__']`

which does not include the function `f`.

But then, after running the line `print(s.f)`, the output is `<bound method A.f of <__main__.B object at 0x00000*******>>`

So my question is, how come `s.f` is not an AttributeError, even though `dir(s)` does not say it has an `f` attribute/method?
I'm using IPython7.19.0 over python3.9.7

Comment: "So my question is, how come s.f is not an AttributeError, even though dir(s) does not say it has an f attribute/method?" Because `dir` is not guarantee of anything. In any case, `super` creates a `super` object, which *doesn't* have that attribute, but it acts as a [*proxy which delegates to the appropriate parent or sibling class*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the docs,
[Python dir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#:%7E:text=If%20the%20object%20does%20not%20provide%20__dir__()%2C%20the%20function%20tries%20its%20best%20to%20gather%20information%20from%20the%20object%E2%80%99s%20__dict__%20attribute%2C%20if%20defined%2C%20and%20from%20its%20type%20object.%20The%20resulting%20list%20is%20not%20necessarily%20complete%20and%20may%20be%20inaccurate%20when%20the%20object%20has%20a%20custom%20__getattr__().)

> If the object does not provide **dir**(), the function tries its best to gather information from the object’s **dict** attribute, if defined, and from its type object. The resulting list is not necessarily complete and may be inaccurate when the object has a custom **getattr**().

Also, as per the docs [Python super()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#:%7E:text=Return%20a%20proxy,after%20the%20type.)

> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type. This is useful for accessing inherited methods that have been overridden in a class.
>
> The object-or-type determines the method resolution order to be searched. The search starts from the class right after the type.

Hence, `s.f` is delegated to the `<bound method A.f of <__main__.B object at 0x00000*******>>`

Here is an excellent explanation of `super()`, https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/